# Why doesn't my guava tree flower and fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees

It has been in the ground in SoCal for about 4 years, and it is probably about 8 ft. tall.  The leaves turn yellow and fall off, and I have not seen one flower yet.

Comment: Can you provide more details such has how often you water and fertilize?  Also, some pictures would be great

Comment: Definitely, pictures!!  Please!